# How to write a rule for firebase

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

I am new to firebase rules, my firebase db is like below

### db

```
school1
   |
   |___classA
   |       |_classData
   |            
   |
   |___students
          |__studentA
          |    |
          |   |__name
          |    |__roles
          |        |
          |        |_admin
          |        |   |__exists : true
          |        |_student
          |            |___exists : true
          |
          |___studentB
                |_name
                |_roles
                    |_admin
                    |    |__exists : false 
                    |_student
                         |_exists : true
```

Now, I want a rule that if the studentA is an admin of classA then he was allowed to get the data of classA otherwise the student is denined to get the data of classA, I tried something like below but failed

```
{
 rules:{
     school1 :{
         classA : {
              ".read":"root.child('school1/students').child('roles/admin').child('exists').val()==true" 
            }
          }
        }
}
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need something like that :

```
{
    "rules": {
        "school1": {
            "classA": {
                ".read":"auth != null && root.child('school1').child('students').child(auth.uid).child('roles').child('admin').child('exists').val() === true" 
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But **studentA** need to be equal to the **user id** present in the auth token.

Comment: I just tried, it's working. Are you really authenticated ? And the user id is really equal to student id ? True is really a boolean ? Not a String ?

Comment: iam not storing the studentA with uid `midhunStudent@gmail|com:{roles:{admin:{exists:true}}}` like this iam storing object in firebase, so how can i equal the student uid to authenticated id @Pipiks

Comment: No ! I'm not talking about email, I'm talking about the user id ! How do you link the user with a student in the database ?

Comment: if i modified auth.uid to mailid what iam setting with custom uid in firebase`{
    "rules": {
        "school1": {
            "classA": {
                ".read":"auth != null && root.child('school1').child('students').child('midhun@gmail|com').child('roles').child('admin').child('exists').val() === true" 
            }
        }
    }
} ` then iam getting the correct answer but i want to check dynamically @Pipiks